# dc.js some data values are not shown

Tags: javascript, json, dc.js

I'm working on a box-plot project with dc.js.

I'm using the example given by the official website from dc.js, but when I used my own json data, the chart shows quite good except some of the data is never shown. Even if I use more data, there are always less box plots than input data.

Here's my code, most of it is same as the [box plot example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Box-Plot Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js"></script>
<div id="box-test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = dc.boxPlot("#box-test")
d3.json( 'http://139.162.34.103/datasets/l0mtun7gdtu3dq5/q2kzx7nvfmahnc8iqocldare7/type=json/limit/100', function( experiments ){
  var ndx                 = crossfilter(experiments.records);
  var xDimension          = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Var;});
  var chartdata           = xDimension.group().reduce(
        function(p,v) {
            console.log(p);//array, empty at first and push data into it
            console.log(v);//object,every row is a object
            p.push(v.OR);
            p.push(v.lower_95);
            p.push(v.upper_95);
            return p;
        },
        function(p,v) {
            //p.splice(p.indexOf(v.OR), 1);
            //p.splice(p.indexOf(v.lower_95), 1);
            //p.splice(p.indexOf(v.upper_95), 1);
            return p;
        },
        function() {
            return [];
        }
      );
  chart
    .width(1000)
    .height(800)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
    .ordering(function(d) {return d.OR;})
    .dimension(xDimension)
    .group(chartdata)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxisPadding('10%');
  chart.tickFormat(d3.format('.3f'));
  dc.renderAll();
});

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
{"name": "tab5_1.csv", 
    "resource_id": "q2kzx7nvfmahnc8iqocldare7",
    "success": "true", 
    "records": [
    {
    "id": 1, 
    "Var": "OCHA", 
    "OR": "0.454647654", 
    "lower_95": "0.351652893", 
    "upper_95": "0.587808299"
    }, 
    {
    "id": 2, 
    "Var": "Arrival_way", 
    "OR": "0.61785793", 
    "lower_95": "0.381860414", 
    "upper_95": "0.999706719"}, 
    {
    "id": 3, 
    "Var": "Coma_M", 
    "OR": "0.636045321", 
    "lower_95": "0.610833258", 
    "upper_95": "0.662298007"}, 
    {
    "id": 4, 
    "Var": "Arrival_way", 
    "OR": "0.681099077", 
    "lower_95": "0.351855361", 
    "upper_95": "1.31842798"}, 
    {
    "id": 5, 
    "Var": "Ais_face", 
    "OR": "0.68451206", 
    "lower_95": "0.635725252", 
    "upper_95": "0.737042863"}
    ]}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting the x scale in your actual code? There is [definitely a bug with quantitative scales](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/792) where the rightmost element gets lost for those charts when using `elasticX`.

Comment: Oh really? I'm a newbie to dc.js.
What should I do?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I was asking if you were setting `.x()` in your actual code, because I don't see how this would happen with an ordinal scale, which is the default for box plots. I have a workaround for quantitative scales but I can't repro the problem using the `box-plot.html` example.

Comment: the code above is my actual code.
I was just testing my own json data and the last data was hidden.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to repro - I must be missing something. Can you edit your question and supply a short example of your data?

Comment: Okay here is the data with only 5 rows

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with that data. I also [tried adding a few more records](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/jy8twao4/8/) but it still displays all of them.

Comment: Do you actually want to aggregate by `Var`? For example with your data above, this would show 4 box plots not 5, because two have `Var: "Arrival_way"`

Comment: oh I see, so the last one is hidden because there are same "Var" name in my data, right?

Comment: So what would you suggest if I want to keep all data, even if the data contains same "Var" name?

Comment: The main idea of crossfilter is to aggregate data, and that's what dc.js animated transitions typically show. If your data is already aggregated then the system might just be cognitive overhead. That said, if you set up your dimension to use something unique like the `id` field then naturally every row will go in its own bin and crossfilter becomes a no-op. It sounds like that's what you want here.

Comment: Alright then, thanks for the help. Are you the author of dc.js?

Comment: Nope but I've maintained it for a few years. Nick Zhu was the original author and since him there have been *lots* of contributors.

Comment: Would you like to copy your answer to the answering part?

Comment: Thanks, I'll write it up next week. I may also edit your question a little bit to make the symptoms clear - I was thrown by "the last one" when it's really any duplicates according to the dimension key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of dc.js is crossfilter, and crossfilter is all about filtering and aggregating data. Crossfilter dimensions define the keys you might want to filter on, and crossfilter groups define the keys to bin and aggregate on, as well as the reduction functions.

If your data isn't aggregated, crossfilter can make filtering and aggregation seems almost magically simple. But if your data is already aggregated, you may feel that you're jumping through hoops. :)

In this case, the data is already aggregated, and then defining the dimension and group on `d.Var` means it will get aggregated again. You're probably getting nonsense results, since you'll end up with more than one set of `OR`, `lower_95`, `upper_95` values in each bin.

If you want each row of your data to go into its own bin, the best way to do that is to use a unique key, like `d.id`, as your dimension key.

If there is no unique key, another solution is to create a crossfilter over the integer indices of your data, as explained in the "Crossfilter on indices" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363805/676195).