# How to show scatter plot on specific condition which I set using dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I want a scatter plot composed with a line chart, but I only want the scatter plot to show when the value is not zero.

I have data as below, range of `val1` is `0~100,` range of `val2` is `-1, 0, 1`

```
[
    {
        val1: 10,
        val2: 0
    },
    {
        val1: 20,
        val2: 1
    },
    {
        val1: 30,
        val2: -1
    },
    {
        val1: 40,
        val2: -1
    },
    {
        val1: 50,
        val2: 1
    },
    {
        val1: 60,
        val2: 0
    },
    {
        val1: 70,
        val2: 0
    },
    {
        val1: 80,
        val2: 1
    },
    {
        val1: 90,
        val2: 1
    },
    {
        val1: 100,
        val2: 1
    }
]
```

[image]

I want to show the line chart of `val1` every tick and I want to put a scatter plot on top of this line when `val2` is `-1` or `1`, not 0. The scatter plot should be colored by the value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another of those places where a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) can come in handy, because we're both transforming a group (by coloring the dots), and omitting some points.

(Despite the ugly name for this pattern, it's quite powerful to do live transformations of the data after it's been aggregated, and this technique will probably shape future versions of dc.js.)

#### Crossfilter on indices

First though, we have to use another unusual technique in order to deal with this data, which has no field which corresponds to the X axis. This may or may not come up in your actual data.

We'll define the crossfilter data as the range of indices within the data, and the dimension key as the index:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(d3.range(experiments.length)),
    dim = ndx.dimension(function(i) { return i; }),
```

Now whenever we read data, we'll need to use the index to read the original array. So the first group (for the line chart) can be defined like this:

```
    group1 = dim.group().reduceSum(function(i) { return experiments[i].val1; });
```

#### Transforming and filtering

Now we get to the heart of the question: how to produce another group which has colored dots for the non-zero `val2` values.

Following the "fake group" pattern, we'll create a function which, given a group, produces a new object with a `.all()` method. The method pulls the data from the first group and transforms it.

```
function keep_nonzeros(group, field2) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return group.all().map(function(kv) {
        return {
          key: kv.key,
          value: {
            y: kv.value,
            color: experiments[kv.key][field2]
          }
        }
      }).filter(function(kv) {
        return kv.value.color != 0
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I chose to first transform the data by adding the color field to the value with `.map()`, and then filter out the zeros with `.filter()`. Most "fake groups" use one or both of these handy Array methods.

#### Building the composite

Now we can build a composite chart using a line chart and a scatter plot:

```
  chart
    .width(600)
    .height(400)
    .x(d3.scale.linear())
    .xAxisPadding(0.25).yAxisPadding(5)
    .elasticX(true)
    .compose([
      dc.lineChart(chart).group(group1),
      dc.scatterPlot(chart).group(keep_nonzeros(group1, 'val2'))
         // https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/870
         .keyAccessor(function(kv) { return kv.key; })
         .valueAccessor(function(kv) { return kv.value.y; })
         .colorAccessor(function(kv) { return kv.value.color; })
         .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([-1,1]).range(['red', 'black']))
    ]);
```

Most of this is boilerplate stuff at this point, but note that we have to set both the key and value accessors for the scatterPlot, because [it makes unusual assumptions about the key structure](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/870) which only matter if you want to do rectangular brushing.

[image: example output]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/6cm8bpym/17/